# How to reload - update de DOM after AJAX code injection?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I thought the easiest way would be to explain it with an image of what I have.

Summary -
I have a form to submit posts (pretty much like what you would find in twitter). Within each post there is an `<ol>` where comments to that post will reside.

Problem - 
When I submit the first comment (button submit 2 in the picture), it doesn't call the ajax and just goes to a page where it presents me the php output of the comment. It seems it is not reloading or aplying DOM events to that portion of code. If I go back, the comment is presented (because it refreshs the page) and when adding the 2nd comment, everything goes normal, as expected. The problem is just the first comment.

Flow - 
1) insert new post
2) click the textarea, put some text and press submit
3) Jumps to a page where php output for comment is presented
3a) no ajax call is done. It never enters the code

Could you please help me out understand what is going on? Thanks in advance.

In case you need more of the code just tell me.

[image]

JS (post_comment.js - associated with submit 2 in picture. I use ajaxForm - jquery form plugin - though I also tried with the standard .ajax call and the result is the same)

```
$(function () {

    var options = {
        success: function (html) {

            var arrHTML = html.split(',');
            var postId = $.trim(arrHTML[0]);
            var html_code = arrHTML[1];

            $('ol#post_comment_list' + postId).load(html_code);
            //$('ol#post_comment_list'+postId 'li:first').slideDown('slow');
            $('.footer-post').hide();
            $('.comments-feed').delay(2000).slideUp({
                duration: 1000,
                queue: true
            });
            $('.small-textarea-main-feed').removeClass('set-large');
            resetForm($('.footer-comment'));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR: unable to upload files');

        },
        complete: function () {

        },
    };

    $(".footer-comment").ajaxForm(options);

    function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var queryString = $.param(formData);
        alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
        return true;
    }

    function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
            .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

    }
});
```

Comment: Well, thanks for all non-comments :\ I have it done now. I just tried it out using onclick instead of grabing the "submit" event and that's it.